# How can I hide the element of the class when the length less than 4?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

1, 2, 3, 4, have some element, but number 5 just has punctuation so I want to hide it.

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

```html
<div>
  <h4>Ingredients</h4>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="cd">
      <strong>1</strong>
      .{{product.item1[0].ing}}: {{product.item1[0].quantity}}{{product.item1[0].unit}}</li>
    <li class="cd">
      <strong>2</strong>
      .{{product.item2[0].ing}}: {{product.item2[0].quantity}}{{product.item2[0].unit}}</li>
    <li class="cd">
      <strong>3</strong>
      .{{product.item3[0].ing}}: {{product.item3[0].quantity}}{{product.item3[0].unit}}</li>
    <li class="cd">
      <strong>4</strong>
      .{{product.item4[0].ing}}: {{product.item4[0].quantity}}{{product.item4[0].unit}}</li>
    <li class="cd1">
    <strong>5</strong>
      .{{product.item5[0].ing}}: {{product.item5[0].quantity}}{{product.item5[0].unit}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<script>var content=document.getElementsByClassName("cd1");if (content.length>1){content.style.display='none';}</script>
```

Comment: Please post your code here, not a screenshot of it.

Comment: Post **code/markup**, not *pictures* of code/markup. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247 Separately: Okay, so, where are you stuck? What has your research turned up? What have you found when [searching](/help/searching)?

Comment: are you using angular 1 or angular 2?

Comment: Avoid using numbers as class names

Answer (score 0):

First of all [**don't mix AngularJS with normal DOM access**, because it won't work (#1)](https://www.toptal.com/angular-js/top-18-most-common-angularjs-developer-mistakes).

Then, considering your DOM and your data structure, it looks like
`product.item(D)(N).ing` is **sometimes** an **empty string** which could be turned into a [`falsy value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Glossary/Falsy) in JavaScript:

```js
function TestCtrl($scope, product) {
  var vm = $scope;

  vm.items = Object.keys(product);
  vm.product = product;
}

angular
  .module('test', [])
  .controller('TestCtrl', TestCtrl)
  .value('product', {
    item1: {
      ing: 'wine',
      quantity: 75,
      unit: 'ml'
    },

    item2: {
      ing: 'pizza',
      quantity: 2,
      unit: 'g'
    },

    item3: {
      ing: 'pasta',
      quantity: 20,
      unit: 'g'
    },

    item4: {
      ing: '', // ng-show will hide item4
      quantity: 1,
      unit: 'kg'
    }
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
<div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
<ol>
<li ng-repeat="itemName in items"
  ng-init="item = product[itemName]"
  ng-show="item.ing">

  {{item.ing}} - {{item.quantity}} - {{item.unit}}
</li>
</ol>

</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Thank you, so how can judge length (.length<1) to show and hide element in Auglar

Comment: read about `falsy values` (link attached) and click `Run code snippet`...